# How to skip test methods inherited from extended abstract test classes

Tags: testng

I'm trying to skip tests based on custom annotation  implemented using IAnnotationTransformer. Skipping tests were successful when set custom annotation in class level, however test methods inherited from extended base class didn't get ignored. If i set the same custom annotation in abstract class, then everything works as expected, but I need to use my abstract class in other places and cannot tag it with custom annotation.

What is the best way to ignore test methods from abstract class. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public abstract class AbstractTestCase {

    @Test()
    public void testMethod1(){
        System.out.println("selenium abstarct1");
    }

    @Test()
    public void testMethod2(){
        System.out.println("selenium abstarct2");
    }
}
```

```
@SetEnvironment(executionEnvironments = {ExecutionEnvironment.STANDALONE})
public class TestSelenium extends AbstractTestCase {

    @Test()
    public void runSelenium1() {
        System.out.println("runSelenium()");
    }

    @Test()
    public void runSelenium2() {
        System.out.println("runSelenium()");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can do it in this ways

1. **Using `<exclude>` tag**
   If you are running your tests using TestNG Suite XML, then you can do something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<suite name="SUITE">
    <test name="TEST">
        <classes>
            <class name="TestClass">
                <methods>
                    <exclude name="excludedTestMethod1" />
                    <exclude name="excludedTestMethod2" />
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

So TestNG will not run `excludedTestMethod1` and `excludedTestMethod2` of class `TestClass`.
Excluded test methods can be in both `TestClass` and `TestClass`'s superclass.

2. **Overriding superclass's test methods**
   In subclass you can override superclass's test methods which you don't want to run. And TestNG will run the overridden ones.
   **2.1** If the overridden method will be marked with `@Test(enabled = false)` annotation then TestNG will not run it
   **2.2** Or you can provide body and write the tests you want in that overridden test methods

Here the example for more detail

```
class TestBase {
    @Test
    public void baseTestMethod() {
        System.out.println("TestBase::baseTestMethod()");
    }

    // ...
}

class TestSub extends TestBase {
    @Test(enabled = false) // if you delete this line, it will print "TestSub::baseTestMethod()"
    public void baseTestMethod() {
        System.out.println("TestSub::baseTestMethod()");
    }

    // ... other test methods
}
```